# Veracrypt Windows Script

Tags: windows, veracrypt

I forgot part of my password to Veracrypt and I need a script for Windows that can go through a .txt file with the possible passwords.

The script needs to only decrypt using the encryption algorithm I know the password to be encrypted with (otherwise it would take a lot longer to decrypt).

Edit: It's not a duplicate, No Windows script was given in any of the other linked posts.

Comment: There is no Windows script in that answer. It's Linux or some other script.

Comment: It's the same question. The "script" mentioned in that answer is the veracode command line options. You can swap out for the Windows versions of the commands by looking up the documentation (https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Command%20Line%20Usage.html). As for how to loop a password brute-force script, that's just batch or Powershell programming, and is beyond the scope of this site.